# angularjs - $destroy isn't called on custom compiled html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a directive that compiles a 'div' with an ng-include and ng-controller, and appends it to the element. It works fine, but for some reason the "$destroy" event isn't called on the controller's scope when it is destroyed.

Is what I'm doing correct?

This is the html:

```
<my-Directive tr-model="someBindedObject"></my-Directive>
```

And this is the JS:

```
angular.module('myModule').
directive('myDirective', function ($compile, controllerMapper) {

    function compileTemplate(scope, element, attrs) {

        var controller = controllerMapper.getController(scope.model);

        innerHtml = '<div ng-include src="' + "'" + controller.templateUrl + "'" + '"  ng-controller="' + controller.controllerName + '" ></div>';

        var innerElement = $compile(innerHtml)(scope);
        element.empty();
        element.append(innerElement);

    };

    return {
        scope: {
            model: "=trModel"
        },
        link: compileTemplate
    }
}).
controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        //this is never called
    });
});
```

Comment: Will give some more details. I could not understanding.

Comment: where is the `$destroy` event handler? WHat should it be doing and what is or isn't happening? Question is very fragmented

Comment: Sorry for being incoherent guys, I edited the question with a (hopefully) better explanation.

Comment: @ramma: Jow are you removing the element ? Have you verified that the controller gets instantiated at all. `ngInclude` might be a terminal directive with higher priority.

Comment: @ExpertSystem: the controller gets instantiated and works normally except this one issue. regarding how i remove the element - basically i have many ng-includes, and i change their value to different views. i figure when the view changes angular should destroy the view's controller, right?

Comment: @ramma: It's not very clear what is going on. Could you provide a fiddle or plunkr that demonstrates the issue ?